# SAPUI5: PDF in iframe blank content

Tags: pdf, sapui5

I've retrieved my pdf from my odata service call. However when I insert to html content using iframe tag, it display a blank page. 
I tried below code. When i hardcode url with drive.google, my app able to show the pdf page but when i remove the hard coded value, my html content not able to render the pdf page. Any inputs on this?

```
// var pdfURL = "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?
//url=https://assets.cdn.sap.com/sapcom/docs/2015/07/c06ac591-5b7c-0010-82c7-
//eda71af511fa.pdf?pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true";
var pdfURL = "https://assets.cdn.sap.com/sapcom/docs/2015/07/c06ac591-5b7c-
0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.pdf";                    
var oHtmlChange = new sap.ui.core.HTML({
content: "<iframe src=" + pdfURL + " width='800' height='800'></iframe>"
});
poFormPanel.addContent(oHtmlChange);
```

Comment: The quotes in the src-attribute are missing?

Comment: Not the quotes. Even i hard coded the whole url instead of using variable also not able to solve

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the following `content` property value:

```js
...
content: "<embed src='https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://assets.cdn.sap.com/sapcom/docs/2015/07/c06ac591-5b7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.pdf' width='800' height='800'>"
...
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/zahikepaya/1/edit?html,output) is a working example.

Comment: Is there any reason why we need to append "Drive.google.com" at the beginning of my actual url? My actual url is "https://assets.cdn.sap.com/sapcom/docs/2015/07/c06ac591-5b7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.pdf", I tried input without "drive.google" context, it's not able to load.

Comment: var poFormPanel = this.getView().byId("container");
var pdfURL = "https://assets.cdn.sap.com/sapcom/docs/2015/07/c06ac591-5b7c-
0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.pdf";                    
var oHtmlChange = new sap.ui.core.HTML({
  content: "<embed src='" + pdfURL + "'width='800' height='800'>"
});
poFormPanel.addItem(oHtmlChange);

Comment: The reason for using drive.google.com is that not every browser can render PDFs natively. See https://pdfobject.com/static.html. UI5 1.48 has a new control "PDFViewer", you can extract the code from their github.

Comment: @Marc, I need to render my pdf in mobile mode. Unfortunately "PDFViewer" from UI5 does not support in mobile mode. It is having a blank page with a download button and it opens the pdf in a new page which is not my expectation.  Is there any other way which I don't append drive.google.com? My pdf is retrieved from oData GET_STREAM service. It is a recomended way by append drive.google as a solution?